# Databricks Python handling with delimiter

Tags: python, csv, pyspark, delimiter

I am using Python in order to make a dataframe based on a CSV file.

The input CSV file looks like this:

[image]

After running the following code:

```
dataframe_sales = spark.read.format('csv').options(header='true',inferSchema='true').load('/mnt/sadwhpostgre001/excel/goud/sales_file.csv')
```

I see that the  some characters on of the column `CompanyName` moved to the right.

See the output file:

[image]

How can I make a dataframe that just keeps the structure of the values on the record? So after making a dataframe the structure must be the same as the input CSV file.

Comment: "The input CSV file looks like this" – that's not what the CSV file *contents* looks like, that's what it looks like *after opening and interpreting it in some graphical application*. We can't see what is used as delimiter in the file.

Comment: Yes ofcourse but due to privacy i cant show you all the details

Comment: I used comma as a delimiter

Comment: And how did you distinguish the comma that is used as delimiter from the comma that is part of the CompanyName?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have a `,` (comma) in the name.

Suggestion: Change the default delimiter to `;` or `|` or something else when you save the file as a CSV.

Then read it from Databricks with the delimiter option enabled:

```
.option("delimiter","your_delimiter_here")
```

Please update your code and change the default delimiter by adding the option:

```
    dataframe_sales = spark.read.format('csv').options(header='true',inferSchema='true').option("delimiter",",").("quote","\"").load('/mnt/sadwhpostgre001/excel/goud/sales_file.csv')
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your response , the issue with the comma on the row level is fixed  but unfortunatly after running your code the dataframe has now only 1 column.  This one column consist "ID","CompanyID","CompanyName","City", "Sales"

How can i make this dataframe with several columns?

Comment: Your CSV file contains the separator as , and it has quotes enabled, so the correct code would be:

    dataframe_sales = spark.read.format('csv').options(header='true',inferSchema='true').option("delimiter",",").("quote","\"").load('/mnt/sadwhpostgre001/excel/goud/sales_file.csv')